# How can i avoid the queries of my spring-boot with hibernate app will be written to console or file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, console

I have an app written in spring-boot.
I have the following files:

**application.properties**

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
debug=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 
    <springProfile name="dev">
        <property name="LOGS" value="...." />
 
        <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
     
        <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOGS}/signing-dev.log</file>
            <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
     
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/signing-dev-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
        </appender>
            
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
     
        <logger name="[mypackage]" level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
        
        <logger name="level.com.zaxxer" level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
        
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
     
        <logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="error" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
  
</configuration>
```

I want to avoid that my hibernate queries will be written to console or file, but they are written like this:

Hibernate: select employeead0_.id as id1_0_0_, employeead0_.type as type2_0_0_ from employee_admin employeead0_ where employeead0_.id=?

How can i configure logback to avoid this?

Comment: When are they written? During Unittests or when you run the app?

Comment: When im running the app

Comment: Try spring.jpa.show-sql=false

Comment: Its already in the application.properties

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Because normally the SQL are not displayed only in DataJpaTests. You don't have to set anything. Is there any other configuration?

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. All is inactive but queries are showing in console. I only have those configurations of above

Comment: Which Spring Boot Version do you use and can you share an example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Use hibernate.show_sql=false

Comment: I have found the error. I have a configuration property when defining jpa:    Map<String,?> additionalJpaProperties(){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout", "20000");
        map.put("spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "5");
        map.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        map.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        
        return map;
    }

Answer (score 0):

try add this to application.properties:

```
#show sql statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=error
#show sql values
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=error
```